# Using Perl I want to filter files with names matching a particular pattern using SFTP

Tags: perl, sftp

I tried the below snippet but it always gets the name of all files present in the current directory.

```
my %args = ("user" => $user, "password" => $pass, "warn" => 0 );

$con= Net::SFTP->new($server, %args);

@files = $con->ls($dir, wanted =>"*.csv");
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is no `wanted` option for the [`ls`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP#$sftp-%3Els($remote-%5B,-$subref-%5D)) method. However, you can pass a callback. Here is an example using [`Text::Glob`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Glob) and a callback function `wanted()`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SFTP;
use Text::Glob qw( match_glob );

my $con= Net::SFTP->new('host', user => 'user', password => 'pass');
my $dir = '.';  # specify the directory

my @files;    # store filenames here
$con->ls($dir, sub { wanted( $_[0], '*.csv') } );

say for @files;  # print the matched filenames

sub wanted {
    my ( $info, $pat ) = @_;

    my $filename = $info->{filename};

    if (match_glob( $pat, $filename ) ) {
        push @files, $filename;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way in Net::SFTP::Foreign module. I believe same should work for Net::SFTP.

```
my @files = map {$_->{'filename'}} grep {$_->{'filename'} =~ /.csv$/i} @{$con->ls("$dir")};
```